# Amazon Glacier Parallel archive upload

Tags: c#, multithreading, amazon-glacier

I have a sample application which upload a file of size 26 MB to Amazon Glacier using AWS SDK for .NET High-Level API. the code works fine without threading but with thread pool its fails at the below line

```
         client.UploadMultipartPart(uploadMPUrequest);
```

saying error Message: 
            The request was aborted: The request was canceled.

Stack Trace: at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.handleHttpWebErrorResponse(AsyncResult asyncResult, WebException we)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.getRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult result)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.InvokeConfiguredRequest(AsyncResult asyncResult)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.InvokeHelper(AsyncResult asyncResult)
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonWebServiceClient.Invoke(AsyncResult asyncResult)
at Amazon.Glacier.AmazonGlacierClient.invokeUploadMultipartPart(UploadMultipartPartRequest uploadMultipartPartRequest, AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Boolean synchronized)
at Amazon.Glacier.AmazonGlacierClient.UploadMultipartPart(UploadMultipartPartRequest uploadMultipartPartRequest)

Note: I am uploading the data in multi part

please find the below link for my sample code:
           [www.page-monitor.com/Downloads/ArchiveUploadMPU.cs](http://www.page-monitor.com/Downloads/ArchiveUploadMPU.cs)

Is there any sample code for parallel upload of archive?

Thanks and Regards,
Haseena

Comment: googling found this git project, maybe it will answer your question: https://github.com/athomason/ParallelGlacierUploader edit:oh just noticed this is a c# question, nevermind

Comment: hey thanks, that actually helped me. Now i am able to parallel y upload the archives to glacier. Thanks again!!

Comment: No problem, google is your friend ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code that works fine with threading. ChunkDetails is a custom library for passing the accessID, bucketname, offset detail, etc. I am also using ThrottledStream.

```
       internal bool UploadUsingHighLevelAPI(String FilePath, ChunkDetails ObjMetaData,
                                            S3Operations.UploadType uploadType,
       Stream inputStream)
       {
       String METHOD_NAME = "UploadUsingHighLevelAPI";
        String keyName;
        String existingBucketName;
        TransferUtilityUploadRequest fileTransferUtilityRequest = null;
        int RetryTimes = 3;
        ThrottledStream throttleStreamObj = null;

        long bps = ThrottledStream.Infinite;
        try
        {


            keyName = ObjMetaData.KeyName;
            existingBucketName = ObjMetaData.BucketName;

            TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new
                    TransferUtility(ObjMetaData.AccessKeyID,        ObjMetaData.SecretAccessKey);

            FileInfo fin = new FileInfo(FilePath);

            //streamObj = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open);

            bps = (long)(1024 * ObjMetaData.MaxAvailSpeed * ((double)ObjMetaData.Bandwidth / 100.0));


            throttleStreamObj = new ThrottledStream(ObjMetaData.FileStream, bps);


            System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection metaInfo = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
            if (ObjMetaData.MetaInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry kvp in ObjMetaData.MetaInfo)
                {
                    metaInfo.Add(kvp.Key.ToString(), kvp.Value.ToString());
                }
            }


            long OffDiff = ObjMetaData.EndOffset - ObjMetaData.StartOffset;
            long partSize;
            if (fin.Length >= OffDiff)
            {
                partSize = OffDiff;
            }
            else
                partSize = fin.Length;



            if (uploadType == UploadType.File)
            {
                //fileTransferUtility.Upload(FilePath, existingBucketName, keyName);


                fileTransferUtilityRequest =
                new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
                .WithBucketName(existingBucketName)
                //.WithFilePath(FilePath)
                .WithStorageClass(S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy)
                .WithMetadata(metaInfo)
                .WithPartSize(partSize)
                .WithKey(keyName)
                .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
                .WithTimeout(Int32.MaxValue - 1)
                .WithInputStream(throttleStreamObj) as TransferUtilityUploadRequest;

            }
            else if (uploadType == UploadType.Stream)
            {
                fileTransferUtilityRequest =
               new TransferUtilityUploadRequest()
               .WithBucketName(existingBucketName)
               .WithStorageClass(S3StorageClass.ReducedRedundancy)
               .WithMetadata(metaInfo)
               .WithPartSize(partSize)
               .WithKey(keyName)
               .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
               .WithTimeout(Int32.MaxValue - 1)
               .WithInputStream(throttleStreamObj) as TransferUtilityUploadRequest
               ;
            }



            for (int index = 1; index <= RetryTimes; index++)
            {
                try
                {

                    // Upload part and add response to our list.
                    fileTransferUtility.Upload(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
                    Console.WriteLine(" ====== Upload Done =========");
                    if (eventChunkUploaded != null)
                        eventChunkUploaded(ObjMetaData);
                    break;

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (index == RetryTimes)
                    {
                        m_objLogFile.LogError(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME + " - Attempt " +
                            index + Environment.NewLine + FilePath, ex);

                        if (eventChunkUploadError != null)
                            eventChunkUploadError(ObjMetaData, ex.Message);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            m_objLogFile.LogError(CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME, ex);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {

            if (throttleStreamObj != null)
            {
                //inputStream1.Close();
                throttleStreamObj = null;
            }
        }

        return true;
   }
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a race condition in the code. I am working on the same functionality. I'd be happy to share code with you. If you fixed the code you posted I'd appreciate a link to it.
Best Regards,
Bruce

Comment: Hi Bruce, please refer to the posted reply for the answer.